# Composer update still shows an older version of a module

Tags: 8, composer

Updating dependencies according to [these instructions](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/update/update-core-via-composer#one-step-update-instruction) offers an older version of the module. Composer.json file has the package required as `"drupal/h5p": "^1.0@RC",` and it used to update just fine. It seems to be stuck with version **rc14** and unable to recognise any changes. It seems like a problem with [packages.drupal.org](https://packages.drupal.org/8) being unable to update the package info.

The instructions on creating an issue about it [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-packagesdrupalorg#what-to-do-if-you-suspect-packagesdrupalorg-is-causing-an-issue) seem to be outdated as that is for a Drupal version 7 project.

Any ideas how could that be resolved? A newer version has been released in the meantime and the package manager is still showing the **rc14** one.

Comment: It also worked for me in case of a fresh Drupal install. Yet it does not want to update an existing one.

Comment: How are you running composer update?

Comment: Using this command: composer update drupal/core webflo/drupal-core-require-dev --with-dependencies

Tough I did try running require again. Might it be a lock file playing games?

Comment: Do you only want to update core, or also other modules?

Comment: The core is up to date. I would just want to update the drupal/h5p as it is the only one that is not up-to-date.

Comment: Try to run `composer update drupal/h5p`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97681/discussion-between-pjotr-and-jdrupal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `h5p` module has 2 dependencies and must therefore be updated like this:

```
composer update drupal/h5p --with-dependencies
```